# How can I take my SOQL out of the loop?

Tags: trigger, soql, query, before-trigger, loop

I have an Id in the `String` format. I'm trying to convert this string into lookup field if it's the `Gear__c` Id. How can I take my SOQL out of the loop?

```
trigger SMSTrigger on Message__c (before insert) {
  for(Message__c msg : Trigger.new){
    if(!String.isEmpty(msg.to_WhatId__c) && msg.to_WhatId__c != null){
        Id neededId = Id.valueOf(msg.to_WhatId__c);
        String objectAPIName  = neededId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;
        if(objectAPIName == 'Gear__c'){
            Gear__c gear = [SELECT Id FROM Gear__c WHERE Id =: neededId];
            if(gear != null){
                msg.Gear__c = gear.Id;
            }    
        }  
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: One more time, why do you need to do SOQL if `neededId` and `gear.Id` should match?

Comment: Is there another way to paste my `Gear__c` object into the lookup field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to convert the string to lookup field, the lookup Id is a string:

```
Id neededId = Id.valueOf(msg.to_WhatId__c);
String objectAPIName  = neededId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;
if(objectAPIName == 'Gear__c'){
    // assign the lookup value
    msg.Gear__c = neededId;
}
```

---

If for some business purpose, you need to refactor the code to avoid query inside a loop, you can use maps. Pseudo code:

```
trigger SMSTrigger on Message__c (before insert) {

    Map<Id, Gear__c> mapGear = new Map<Id, Gear__c>();
    // collect map of gears
    for(Message__c msg : Trigger.new){
        if(!String.isEmpty(msg.to_WhatId__c) && msg.to_WhatId__c != null){
            mapGear.put(msg.to_WhatId__c, null);
        }
    }

    // query the gears related to keys
    mapGear = new Map<Id, Gear__c>([SELECT Id FROM Gear__c WHERE Id IN :mapGear.keySet()]);

    for(Message__c msg : Trigger.new){
        if(!String.isEmpty(msg.to_WhatId__c) && msg.to_WhatId__c != null){
            Id neededId = Id.valueOf(msg.to_WhatId__c);
            String objectAPIName  = neededId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;
            if(objectAPIName == 'Gear__c' && mapGear.containsKey(neededId)) {
                // retrieve the geat from Map
                msg.Gear__c = mapGear.get(neededId).Id;
            }  
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger SMSTrigger on Message__c (before insert) {
    for(Message__c msg : Trigger.new){
       if(!String.isEmpty(msg.to_WhatId__c) && msg.to_WhatId__c != null){
            Id neededId = Id.valueOf(msg.to_WhatId__c);
            String objectAPIName  = neededId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;
            if(objectAPIName == 'Gear__c'){
               msg.Gear__c = neededId;
            }  
        }    
    }
 }
```

there is no need to query